# What is the factor group $C_{12}/C_{6}$?

Tags: group-theory, cyclic-groups, quotient-group

I know this factor group is isomorphic to $C_2$, but I have tried calculating it and I only get one coset.

Comment: We have the coset $e C_6=C_6$ and another one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$C_6$, as a subgroup of $C_{12}$, contains $6$ of the $12$ elements. The remaining $6$ must make up the second coset.

Specifically, if
$$
C_{12} = \{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11\}
$$
with addition modulo $12$ as the group operation, then the two cosets of $C_6$ are
$$
C_6 = \{0,2,4,6,8,10\}\\
1 + C_6 = \{1,3,5,7,9,11\}
$$